# How to keep the caret blinking in Windows Application

Tags: winapi, window, caret

In a Win32 application, I want the caret to blink continuously but the default caret timeout (for which there is some registry entry) makes the caret disappear after 5 blinks. Is there some way to change the caret timeout/no. of times it can blink for a specific application?

The caret reference (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/carets) has APIs to create, show, hide, position and change the blink time. However I didn't find any API or a way to change the caret timeout.

One way I could think of was to install a timer with duration that of the caret timeout entry and then in `WM_TIMER`, use caret APIs `HideCaret` and `ShowCaret`.

Comment: This seems to be an [undocumented feature](https://superuser.com/q/1436937/411775) of the Windows Edit Control. Just set `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\CaretTimeout` to some large value like `0xFFFFFFFF` if it bothers you. I don't know of any way to specify the timeout for a specific application.

Comment: @Axalo Yes, I am looking for a programmatic way such that it only affects my application.

Comment: `SPI_SETCARETTIMEOUT` is available from RS3 which you use via `SystemParametersInfo()`. It is not documented yet but it is in the SDK header file.And what you're doing is correct with the UIAutomation `AddFocusChangedEventHandler`.

Comment: @DrakeWu-MSFT Thanks for SPI_SETCARETTIMEOUT. Is there any such application specific API? Also can you please elaborate ".And what you're doing is correct with the UIAutomation AddFocusChangedEventHandler"? I was talking about win application using C++.

Comment: This solution is system wide.  There isn’t a solution for a specific application. If you want the function for application level, you could submit the feedback on Feedback Hub app(please share link here if you submitted so that people with the same problems could know the progress.)